# Most famous research papers to get started in quant finance

Tags: statistics, statistical-finance, econometrics, modelling

I have a strong background in finance and I know how to code, but I am lacking the statistical modelling part. I have started courses in mathematics and statistics. However, it is turning out very difficult to adapt that general knowledge to the actual in-use strategies.

So, I have thought about starting with papers that anyone who is in quant finance knows, and starting from there the research on finance modelling. Does anybody have some recommendation on some papers?

Comment: Hi: It's best to be as specific as possible so finance modelling of what ? There are so many models of so many things ( capm, volatility, equity returns etc, etc ) so it's not possible to answer your question in a succinct manner.

Comment: @Kevin this was what I was looking for! I did not find that answer. Yes, mark leeds I know... I was looking for something like Kevin mentioned